# EF 2.1 get all users in roles

Tags: asp.net, .net-core

I have a .NET Core 2.1 with EF 2.1 application and I'd like to directly query an existing ASP.NET MVC database to get the users and roles.

Specifically I'd like to pass in an array of strings representing the role names, and find the distinct list of users in those roles.

I have code that works at the moment but feels really inefficient - I basically iterate through the roles array and get a list of all the users, then do a Union

```
var accounts = GetAllUsersInRole("Accounts").ToList();
var managers = GetAllUsersInRole("Manager").ToList();

users = (managers.Union(accounts).ToList();

public IQueryable<ApplicationUser> GetAllUsersInRole(string roleName)
    {
        var idsWithPermission = _context.AspNetRoles.Where(x => x.Name == roleName)
            .Select(p => p.UserId);

var users = _context.AspNetUsers.Where(u => idsWithPermission.Contains(u.Id)).ToList();
        return users.AsQueryable();
    }
```

I'm hoping I missed a way to this easily with EF2.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is by using the `UserManager` which is provided by ASP.NET Identity.

```
private UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager; 

public AccountController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager) {
   _userManager = userManager;
}
```

The `UserManager` should automatically be registered in the DI container if you have set up Identity correctly in Startup.cs

Then all you need to do is call `await _userManager.GetUsersInRoleAsync(rolename);`